# postgres, update with statement halts

Tags: postgresql

my query,

```
WITH vista AS (
  SELECT
    transaction_id,
    SUM (item_total) AS items_total,
    SUM (item_total) * 0.2 AS discount_value,
    (SUM (item_total) * 0.8) * 0.16 AS tax,
    (SUM (item_total) * 0.8 * 1.16) AS grand_total
  FROM lineitems_vista
  GROUP BY transaction_id
)
UPDATE transactions
SET
  items_total = vista.items_total,
  discount_id = 5,
  discount_value = vista.discount_value,
  tax = vista.tax,
  grand_total = vista.grand_total
FROM vista
WHERE id = transaction_id;
```

which is updating only 302 rows has been at it for around an hour now. Where i am doing it wrong?

Comment: have you got an index on `transactions.id`?
What does `EXPLAIN ` *that query* say ?

Comment: It's probably waiting to acquire a lock: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: yes, there is an index on transactions.id .. and thankyou,